# Is it possible? - Have multiple DHCP ranges in a single subnet

Tags: networking, dhcp, dell

I have a testing environment of 10 lightly-populated racks. I'll be installing a single 1 Gb switch in each rack with 10 Gb uplinks to a single central switch.

What I would like to have is for DHCP addresses to be assigned from a specific pool for each rack but have everything on a single subnet (no vlans).

ie:

- Rack 1 - 172.16.101.x 255.255.0.0
- Rack 2 - 172.16.102.x 255.255.0.0
- Rack 3 - 172.16.103.x 255.255.0.0

**Is this possible?**

*Equipment:*

- [Force10 S55](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/force10-s55/fs) for each rack
- [Force10 4810](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/force10-s4810/fs) central switch

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though each Force10 switch is able to be a DHCP server ([page 246](https://www.force10networks.com/CSPortal20/KnowledgeBase/DOCUMENTATION/CLIConfig/FTOS/S55_ConfigGuide_13-Dec-2010.pdf)), so it looks like this should be simple:

1. Set up each switch to have its own non-overlapping DHCP pool in the same subnet
2. Filter DHCP from the uplink ports to ensure DHCP traffic doesn't travel to the other switches (this could be done on each TOR switch, or at your central switch).

I note that you're using three /24 networks, but a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0; a mask of 255.255.252.0 (or a /22) would limit your subnet to exactly those three /24's

Comment: Thanks. Depending on how this works we may be rolling the same equipment out to other labs so that management is a single network. We'd probably leave the 255.255.0.0 as we could be adding in quite a few more racks 

Though I'd assume if we get too much equipment on the same subnet, I'd have other issues to worry about? Max would be 120 racks. (this network sees light traffic. RDP for management, PXE when we do installs, SSH, etc. )

Comment: @theeldest - fair enough. Just be careful that you're not flooding your network with needless broadcast traffic by creating gigantic subnets when they're not actually required.

Comment: You caught me between edits. That's one of the things we'll be considering. Once the hardware is set up I'll be doing some monitoring to see what the broadcast traffic actually looks like. If we run into issues we'll start carving up separate subnets. Thanks again!